Returning NaN for Generic Type of INumber<T>
I am currently working on a project which has various classes to do mathematical operations.  To make it generic, the classes are defined with a generic constraint using INumber<T>.  However, I am running into an issue where I need to return NaN but can't seem to find a way using the generic parameters.
For example, say I have a class Divide defined as such:
public class Divide<T> where T : INumber<T>
{
    public T Evaluate()
    {
        var divisor = Child[1].Evaluate();
        if (divisor.CompareTo(0) == 0)
        {
            //How can I return NaN here for T?
        }

        var dividend = Child[0].Evaluate();
        return dividend / divisor;
    }
}

I even search for a way to return some kind of infinity and use that as my indication of NaN without luck.  Is there no way to return some kind of generic NaN excluding throwing an exception (which I am trying to avoid)?

int, long etc also implement INumber, but there is no infinity/NaN values for them. What do you want to happen when T is int or long? How about restricting T to types that have infinity/NaN values? IFloatingPointIeee754, for example.

Or just return a (T?)null and restrict T to struct.

@Sweeper I didn't even think about ints.  Ugh...might have to rethink these classes.  Thanks for pointing this out; probably just saved me a days worth of time.

There isn't a way of returning NaN in C# with generics, but you can restrict T to a type with NaN, like double.NaN For instance, the code below can help:
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(double.NaN, typeof(T));

This method might be a problem if you want to support other types that don't have NaN, such as Integers.
You can also create a separate class or struct to handle the result of DivisionResult. You can return this new class instead.

That may work for this case.  I will definitely try it out and see how it goes.  Thanks for the suggestion.
